# Redirect all access from a folder to a PHP file

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to do a task like this.

I have a folder /doc/ with many documents files inside. When an user trying to access this folder's content, I need to do some verification, so I need to redirect that access to a download.php file in root folder and pass the actual REQUEST_URI to PHP file. I try this in htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.com/doc.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/download.php?r=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But I got ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error with the redirected url is: download.php?r=/download.php, which in this case is not what I want (download.php?r=/doc/abc/xyz.pdf is the correct one)

Could someone explain for me about what I did wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your rewrite cond line is incorrect and it will continue looping forever. You'll need to add a File check so it doesn't use the rewrite condition every time. So it will only use it when it's pointing to a file that doesn't exist
add the following lines RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rewritecond line is incorrect and it will continue looping forever. You'll need to add a File check so it doesn't use the rewrite condition every time. So it will only use it when it's pointing to a file that doesn't exist
add the following lines

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^doc\/(.*)\.html$ download.php?r=$1 [L,R=301]
```

with the url http://example.com/doc/file.html

it will redirect the user to download.php?r=file if you wanted to capture the file extension change the last line to

```
RewriteRule ^doc\/(.*)$ download.php?r=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: HI, thank you for your answer. Let's say I want to redirect http://example.com/doc/file.html to http://example.com/download.php.

Comment: Thanks, but how to redirect all url within /doc/ folder, like /doc/star/file.pdf and /doc/biz/new/file.html?

Comment: The second part of my answer will do that. You'll get r=star/file.pdf in the download script and you can do the processing from there

Comment: ah sorry, get rid of the !-f line. I will update my answer